# Extracting categories from each cell and encoding it

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I need to encode values of column1. I know when the dtype is categorical or in case it has only one value. But for this scenario, what should I do?

```
Column1  x_val y_val z_val 
   x; y    1     1     0
   y;z;x   1     1     1 
   x       1     0     0
   z;x     1     0     1
   x       1     0     0
   NaN     ?     ?     ?
```

**Note**: x_val, y_val, z_val are the desired columns

Comment: What is your desired outout?

Comment: x_val, y_val, z_val are the desired

Comment: What exactly do you mean by encoding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.Str.get_dummies`:

```
new_df = df["Column1"].str.get_dummies(";").add_suffix("_val")
new_df.loc[~new_df.any(1)] = '?'
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  x_val y_val z_val
0     1     1     0
1     1     1     1
2     1     0     0
3     1     0     1
4     1     0     0
5     ?     ?     ?
```